# phraseto_tsquery on text array using postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following two tables

trigger_keyword table

```
CREATE TABLE trigger_keyword
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    keyword_array text[],
    CONSTRAINT trigger_keyword_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

trigger_message table

```
CREATE TABLE trigger_message
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    message text NOT NULL,
    trigger_keyword_id bigint,
    CONSTRAINT trigger_message_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I have the following test data

trigger_keyword table

```
id   keyword_array
-----------------------------------------------------
1    {weather, climate}
```

trigger_message table

```
id   message                   trigger_keyword_id
-----------------------------------------------------
1    yes, the weather is good  1
2    expect rain               1
3    partly cloudy             1
```

The following query works as expected if the keyword column in `trigger_keyword` is `text`, but it does not work when the column is `text[]`

```
SELECT m.message
FROM trigger_keyword AS k
   JOIN trigger_message AS m ON k.id = m.trigger_keyword_id
WHERE to_tsvector('simple', 'tell me the weather')
      @@ phraseto_tsquery('simple', k.keyword); <-- this would become k.keyword_array after removing the text column and adding a text[] column
```

How can I modify the query above to work with array of text instead of text?

with the text array I can add more keywords easily, in this case "tell me the climate" would also return rows from the trigger_message table

I know the recommended way to do this is to use a bridge table, but editing it and matching things becomes cumbersome, so I would like to use an array instead.

Comment: I told you not to mess with arrays. Now you see what comes from that: slow, complicated queries.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  You are right, but managing the bridge table with just IDs is a bit time consuming. But looks like there is no better alternative

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I went back to using the bridge table. https://pastebin.com/qNBh48i4